# Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in

Tags: php, ssh

I'm Using PHP 8.1 ssh2_connect
but error

```
Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in
```

this is my code :

```
if(function_exists("ssh2_connect")) {
        $ssh_conn = ssh2_connect($ip, $port);
        if($ssh_conn) {
            //Validate your username with ssh keys
            if(env("TRAEFIK_METHOD")=="KEY"){
                $connect = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh_conn, $username, $public_ssh_key, $private_ssh_key, 'secret');
            }else{
                $connect = ssh2_auth_password($ssh_conn, $username, $password);
            }

            if($connect) {

                $stream2 = ssh2_exec($ssh_conn, "printf '".$file_content."' > ".$file_dir."".$file_name);
                if($stream2){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            //    ssh2_scp_send($ssh_conn, '/Users/wauputra/Documents/owner-app/README.md', '/home/pena', 0777);
            
            }
            else {
                die("SSH validation failed using Username: ".$username." (specify valid SSH keys or check your SSH key path)");
            }
        }else {
            die("SSH validation failed for IP: ".$ip);
        }
    }else {
        die("'ssh2_connect()' doesn't exists. Install libssh2 with PECL SSH2 extension");
    }
```

i've installed pecl ssh2
it's work on localhost, but error on stagging

Comment: Although not an answer to your problem, I have found that using the [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/connect) library solves most of the pains I have with SSH (and SFTP), and it might help you, if not solve the problem, at least diagnose it further

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after i change other ssh connection, the error is done

i think the problem is my ssh connection, though when i running on local it's work fine